# Instance Types missing while creating Server Group in Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I have used AWS Community AMI for configuring Spinnaker. I am able to get the lists of ELB, AMI and Security Groups while creating Server Group. But, I am not getting the Instance types in the custom drop down list. Any idea about what could be going wrong?

[Spinnaker Cluster Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXTwy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not having a correct IAM role assigned to the user whose access keys you are using for the spinnaker integration with AWS.

Mostly if you used the spinnaker.Check if you have enough rights in AWS.
If not then create a role and assign AWS POWER USER ACCESS to your user and then try to get the integration .

Spinnaker is a tool which would need AWS EC2 Full access atleast as it directly access EC2 spin up its server groups.

Answer (score 0):

Instance types are cached in the browser's local storage. You can explicitly refresh the cache via the 'Refresh all caches' link:[image]

If you show the network tab of your browser's console (prior to clicking 'Refresh all caches'), you should see a request to http://localhost:8084/instanceTypes.

If the response contains your instance types, you should be good to go.

Comment: I have tried refreshing the cache several times but I am still getting empty list as a response for Instance Types. I have launched Spinnaker server with IAM role specified in the configuration guide. Is there any configuration that might be missing?

Comment: You could check the clouddriver logs to see if there are any exceptions: http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/troubleshooting-guide#section-check-service-logs

My clouddriver logs have entries like:
2016-03-30 20:56:33.346  INFO 13187 --- [cutionAction-31] s.c.a.p.a.AmazonInstanceTypeCachingAgent : Caching 645 items in my-aws-account/us-east-1/AmazonInstanceTypeCachingAgent

Comment: There are no exceptions in the clouddriver log. I don't understand why the Instance types are not getting populated. InstanceTypes are being cached but every time its an empty list.  Even if I try and select different utility under InstanceType like "micro-utility" the available Instance types are disabled with the info **instance types not available for the given configuration**. Is this a known Spinnaker issue?